# Mudar título da aplicação em Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Não estou conseguindo tirar essa *string* `$projectname$` do meu título em uma aplicação em Xamarin Android.

Já tentei editar o `AndroidManifest.xml` e  `AssemblyInfo.cs` e nada. Procurei por essa *string* no projeto inteiro e também não achei.

Esse erro começou a ocorrer depois da última vez que atualizei o Xamarin.

Alguém já passou por isso também?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Você pode colocar o label em cima da activity, assim:

```
[Activity (Label="Awesome Demo App")]
```

Para mais informações: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Activity_Title_Bar